# How does this js enclosure work?

Tags: javascript

Here is code of a page:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is an enclosure in the script. As i understand, each time when add is called, the counter must be set to zero again, so it doesn't grow when clicking on the button. But as practice shows, my conclusion is wrong. Please tell me, why the counter is not reset each time when the fumction add is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated code, the correct behavior is for `counter` to NOT reset to zero and increase by one.

```
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();
```

The reason is because the function you return and assign to add is only this part:

```
function () {return counter += 1;}
```

Every time you call `add()` only that is called. The reason is because you have an anonymous function that declares `counter` and returns a function. That function gets placed into `add` and traps the `counter` variable in a closure.

Comment: Excuse me for stupidity. I understand that each time we get a new function with new variable <code>counter</code>. But before returning `function () {return counter += 1;}` the interpreter must go through code line `var counter=0`, so the local variable outside of anonymous function will be changed to 0 and the anonymous function will refer to this value. What do i understand wrong?

Comment: No function(){return counter+=1} is only returned once. That effectively becomes add. So when you call add you are calling the same function counter already inside of it.

The code that declares counter is only called once when add is created that's it. Everytime add is called it is not called only the  function being returned is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it into a seperate function for true closure, then you can call the function.

```
<body>

<p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>

<p id="demo">0</p>

<script>
var add = function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var x = function () {return counter += 1;}
    return x();
};

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>
</body>
```